# The strict inequality work but strict equality not. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is a part of an embed in discord.js bot. The first string work (the channels' string) the other not. I think the problem is ===, because if i use !=== to exlude all the other cases it work, but i want to know if i can use === to specify the only value i want.

When i start the bot and i run the command in my discord server the bot doesnt go in error, the bot stays on and in the console aren't log. The only things is that in the embed this values are 0. All of this (category, text, voice) are 0, the one is the correct value is channels counter, the section that use !==.

I try also to sobstitute the strings with for exapmle channeltype.text but it tell me that channeltype doesn't exist.

```js
"**Channels:** `" +
  (await interaction.guild.channels.fetch()).filter(
    (c) => c.type !== "GUILD_CATEGORY"
  ).size +
  "`" +
  "\n" +
  "**Category:** `" +
  (await interaction.guild.channels.fetch()).filter(
    (c) => c.type === "GUILD_CATEGORY"
  ).size +
  "`" +
  "\n" +
  "**Text:** `" +
  (await interaction.guild.channels.fetch()).filter(
    (c) => c.type === "GUILD_TEXT"
  ).size +
  "`" +
  "\n" +
  "**Voice:** `" +
  (await interaction.guild.channels.fetch()).filter(
    (c) => c.type === "GUILD_VOICE"
  ).size +
  "`" +
  "\n";
```

Im tryning to get the amount of categorys, text channels and voice channels in separated values.

Comment: What does your debugging tell you? You could easily log the values to see what they are and why they don't match

Comment: Channel types not strings anymore. Use the `ChannelType` enum from Discord.JS to check the channel type. Example: `c.type === ChannelType.GuildText`

Comment: more info on @Elitezen's answer: the `===` operator always considers operands of different type to be different, so because you're comparing a `ChannelType` to a `String` this will always return false.  You would actually be better off using `==` as this will compare in a more useful way in this instance.  (`===` is more like asking "are these the same object")

Comment: it doesnt work.